# PHP CSV parse issue escaping strings for MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv, addslashes

I'm trying to parse a number of CSV files from a product feed.  I'm using the code below to grab the data from the CSV, and process row by row for insertion in to a MySQL db.  For some reason every once and a while the addslashes function seems to skip the escape sequence.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 2000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{           
    $num = count($data);
    $nl = 0; 

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++)  
    {
        $nl++;  
        if ($c >= 0)
        {
            if ($nl == 1)
            {
                $Name = addslashes($data[$c]);
            }
            if ($nl == 2)
            {
                $URL = $data[$c];
            }
            if ($nl == 3)
            {
                $CatalogName = addslashes($data[$c]);
            }
            if ($nl == 4)
            {
                $LastUpdated = $data[$c];
            }
        }
    }
    if ($headerRow > 40) 
    {   
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table (name,url,catname,updated) VALUES ('$Name','$URL','$CatalogName','$LastUpdated')";
                mysqli_query($connection3,$sql) or die("Can't execute query I001.);
    }
}
```

Comment: Either use parametrized queries, or use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: Why are you injecting values into the SQL query if you're using MySQLi? Use prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: I also don't understand why you're using a `for` loop. Just do `$Name = addslashes($data[1]); $URL = $data[2]; etc.`

Comment: Please fix your code indentation. It looks like the query is inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @Barmar if I use `mysqli_real_escape_string` how to I "unescape" the values when I read them back out of the db?

Comment: The escapes are not stored in the DB, they're just used to make the SQL query parse correctly.

Comment: @Robert82 DONT use real_escape_string.  Use prepared statements.  The database engine will assume the data is dangerous and will just accept it rather than "process" it like it would in a concatenated statement like you have.

Comment: @Snowburnt  I'm not sure what you mean by just accept vs process it.

Comment: Also, I've not used prepared statements before.  How would I set up the insert above as a prepared statement?  btw, I don't generally use objects, I generally use procedures.

Comment: @Robert82 it doesn't build out a string containing your data, you give it the string, tell it where the data goes and it says "okay, that's data" so if someone put in a `' or '1'='1' -- '` it would look at that string and say: I'll just put that in the database as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a parameterized query (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

```
$sql=$connection3->prepare("INSERT INTO table (name,url,catname,updated) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
$sql->bind_param('ssss',$Name,$URL,$CatalogName,$LastUpdated);
$results=$sql->execute(); //results contains whether or not the execute was successful.
```

While this is "Object oriented style" the actual functionality of this statement will work whether or not you prefer "objects" to "procedural style", it's all in the style.  In any case, it will work and there are procedural examples in the docs.

in fact, here's how you do it procedurally:

```
$stmt=mysqli_prepare($connection3, "INSERT INTO table (name,url,catname,updated) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $Name,$URL,$CatalogName,$LastUpdated);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Now you don't have to worry about escaping your statement, but you still do have to sanitize your entries to prevent cross site scripting and other security risks.

Comment: Would I include all 3 statements on every iteration of the loop, or just do the first line once outside the loop, and the last two statements on every iteration?

Comment: You can set up the prepare outside the loop then bind the parameters and execute inside the loop